# Bubble-sort 'works' in Windows, but not with GCC on GNU/Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, syntax, gnu

I am using Ubuntu Linux for programming purposes. Yesterday I came across a very strange problem that was really really obscure and was weird.

The problem was that I tried to do bubble sort, logic, syntax everything was correct but the output was wrong. I wrote same program in Windows and it worked fine. I am using Eclipse IDE in Linux. What can be the problem? On The other side I used pointers (call by reference) to accomplish bubble sort, but in Ubuntu the output was also wrong, while in Windows the output was okay. I don't know how to figure it out.

My code for bubble sort is as following:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
  int array[] = {4,2,6,3,1,5,8,4,6,1};
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<=10-i;j++)
        {
          if(array[j]>array[j+1])
            {
              int temp = array[j];
              array[j] = array[j+1];
              array[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
  for(i=0;i<=9;i++)
    {
      printf("%d\t",array[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
gcc -o bubblesort.c -o output
./output


2 3 4 1 5 6 4 6 1 1
```

Comment: First time through the second loop, you'll reach `i=1`, `j=9`, `array[j+1]` is an invalid access => your code exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: `GNU C compiler Linux output is wrong` -- it's extremely rare for this statement to mean what you thought it meant when you typed it. Almost always, it means you have messed something up, not the compiler.

Comment: @mah - I edited the title, among other things. Hope it is closer to fact now (and more specific)

Answer (score 4):

Going beyond the bounds of an array is undefined behaviour (a subset of which is behave "correctly"), which is what is occuring the program. Arrays use a zero-based indexed meaning the last valid index is one less than the number of elements in the array:

```
/* 10 elements in 'array'. */
int array[] = {4,2,6,3,1,5,8,4,6,1};

for(j=0;j<=10-i ;j++)
{
    if(array[j]>array[j+1]) /* When 'j' is 9 the
                               'array[j + 1]' is
                               out of bounds. */
```

Change the inner `for` loop terminating condition:

```
for(j=0;j<=9-i ;j++)
```

---

Instead of hard-coding `9` and `10` throughout the code you could use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` to obtain the number of elements in `array`. This makes it less error prone and simpler to change the number of elements in `array` later:

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
```

Comment: can you explain how the behaviour is undefined ?.. there are 10 elements in an array and the rule for bubble sort is that outer loop should be <=sizeofarray and inner loop <=sizeofarray-i if i am wrong can you clear me ?

Comment: @JamalHussain, I mistakenly thought `i` was being used to index (updated answer). it is not, but the indexing of `j + 1` is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
for(j=0;j<=10-i;j++)
```

together with this:

```
if(array[j]>array[j+1])
```

and other places where you access your array out of bound is a likely cause of your problems.

Accessing an array out of bounds is *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

This is pseudo code for a bubble sort:

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {
        if (element[i] > element[j]) swap_elements();
```

Comment: thanks it did worked. but I am surprised why my code is working in windows net beans. isn't it strange ?

Comment: @JamalHussain: Your code invokes "Undefined Behaviour". It literally means that the code can behave in completely arbitrary ways. One of the most insidious results of UB is when the code does exactly what you want, only to blow up in your face later.